# Verificar si dentro del array hay valores en blanco, si los hay que me muestre un mensaje y se cierre

Tags: c#, array

Resulta que tengo 10 textbox en un form y cuando se guarda  necesito que verifique cuales de los textbox están vacíos y que me mande un solo mensaje diciendo cuales son los textbox que estan vacios. Cabe aclarar que no todos los 10 textbox son obligatorios por ese la idea de filtrar con la etiqueta tag.

```
    private void verificarcontroles()
    {
        int cont = 0;
        string[] nombres = new string[10];

        foreach (Control a in this.Controls)                 
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(a.Name);

            if (a is TextBox)                         
            {

                if (a.Tag is "1")
                {
                    if (cont < 5)
                    {

                        nombres[cont] = a.Text;
                        cont++;

                        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(cont));
                        //MessageBox.Show(a.Text);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombres))
```

Comment: Hola, cual seria tu inconveniente?

Comment: Necesito verificar cuales de los datos del array son nulos o estan en blanco y mostrar un mensaje diciendo cuales de los texbox estan vacios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string mensaje = "Se detectaron los siguientes campos vacíos:\n\n"    
bool vacio = false;

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is TextBox && c.Tag.ToString() == "1")
   {
      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((TextBox)c).Text))
      {
         vacio = true;
         mensaje += ((TextBox)c).Name + "vacío\n";
      }
   }
} 

if(vacio)
{
   MessageBox.Show(mensaje);
}
```

Se recorren todos los controles del formulario y se preguntan si son de tipo **TextBox** y si su **propiedad** **Tag** es igual a **1**, posteriormente se pregunta si el texto del **TextBox** que se está analizando está vacío a través de la **función** **IsNullOrWhiteSpace**, de estar vacío la **variable vacio** toma valor **true** y en la **variable mensaje** se escribe que ese **TextBox** está vacío, uso la **propiedad** **Name** del **TextBox** para referirme al **TextBox** que está vacío.

Al salir del ciclo se pregunta si la **variable vacio** es **true**, de ser cierto quiere decir que por lo menos hay un **TextBox** vacío, por tanto se muestra mediante un **MessageBox** los **TextBox** que se encontraron vacíos.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfecto, era mucho mas fácil de lo que había pensado.

Comment: @FelipeMorales, si la respuesta te fue util por favor dale un voto y marcala como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Donde hago eso?

Comment: En la respuesta, debe haber un checkmark, da clic ahi y el voto es al lado en un boton en forma de triangulo con el piquito hacia arriba

Comment: Listo hecho gracias.